# Twitter bootstrap restrict scrolling to one div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I am new to Bootstrap and have the following setup at the moment:

```
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  ...
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container text-center">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to use `affix` or something similar to allow the user to scroll like normal, but the navbar, jumbotron and the nav-pill list on the side should all stay fixed. So in essence the only thing that would scroll is the content on the right of the pills. I tried doing this with `affix` myself but wasn't sure of what to set the offset so was unable to achieve the intended result. I'd be grateful for a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think for your purpose it'd be best to only worry about **affix** for the side nav, and use CSS positioning for your Jumbotron (just like Bootstrap does for the navbar at the top).

For the **jumbotron**, set the position to fixed and give it an explicit top (50px is the height of the navbar above it), set the width to 100% if you want it to stretch across the viewport, and give it an explicit height. Then set the z-index to a value higher than 1 and less than 1030 (the z-index given to the navbar by Bootstrap). This will make sure your content scrolls behind your jumbotron.

CSS for the jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron{
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Then create your container and give it a margin-top of *(navbar height) + (jumbotron height) + (any desired margin)*, in our example this is 250px + a 30px margin. This will ensure your page is positioned below the fixed nav and jumbotron.

```
#container-id{
    margin-top:280px;
}
```

For the **side-nav**, in your **ul** element include `data-spy="affix"`. You don't need to set any value for `data-offset-top` because you want your side-nav to be fixed in place immediately.

Here's a jsfiddle with an example navbar and sidenav plus your daily dose of lorem ipsum: http://jsfiddle.net/3LLZR/

Comment: Perfect, except its not very responsive (as the columns stack it looks very ugly). Is there a way to apply the CSS to jumbotron and the affix only if the columns aren't stacked?

Comment: Yes, add it in the min-width at the break point you selected for your menu.

Comment: I've also seen the sidenav replaced by a fixed nav styled differently by using **hidden-xs** etc to hide the sidenav and **visible-xs** to render replacement content accordingly.

There also seems to be some contention about this/a bug report for similar issues mentioned in a previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512168/