# Bootstrap affix content within pushed column breaks layout in safari at the time of scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, affix

Yes, this is some kind of [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512168/bootstrap-affix-menu-within-a-pushed-column-overlaps-main-content-in-safari-when) posted 1 year ago by someone. I like to know have there any good solutions came for this `so far` ? [Issue for this at github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12126) is also closed :( I need a `solution` for this badly. Please, open [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq1bgpnk/) from Safari to see the problem as it's only happened at Safari.

At **safari**:

(a) Normal
[image]

(b) At the time of scrolling:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Affix menu within a pushed column overlaps main content in Safari when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512168/bootstrap-affix-menu-within-a-pushed-column-overlaps-main-content-in-safari-when)

Answer (score 2):

Add to CSS:

```
.box.affix {
    position:absolute;
}
```